# Resolving GeoIP coordinates in development mode

Tags: python, django, geolocation, django-forms

I'm trying to insert the lat, lon directly into a form using GeoIP. There have been issues, more than likely because I'm in development mode with local host and the IP address can't be properly resolved.

I'm trying to create a dummy IP address just to see if the lat, lon are actually being determined and set in the form ('google.com'). Unfortunately, this is causing problems with other elements in the form not being properly saved, specifically the author attribute.

The resulting error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'
```

This is the view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from myapp.report.models import Story, UserProfile
from myapp.report.forms import ProfileForm, StoryForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
from django.conf import settings

@login_required
def submit_story(request):
    remote_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    if settings.DEBUG:
        remote_address = 'google.com'

    if request.method =="POST":
        story_form = StoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if story_form.is_valid():
            new_story = story_form.save(ip_address=remote_address)
            new_story.author = request.user
            new_story.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/report/all/")
    else: # GET request
        story_form = StoryForm()
    return render_to_response("report/report.html", {'form': story_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is the model:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    objects = StoryManager()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    copy = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="stories")
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures', blank=True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return " %s" % (self.title)
```

This is the form:

```
from django import forms
from myapp.report.models import UserProfile, Story
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

class StoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        exclude = ('author','latitude', 'longitude')

    def save(self, ip_address, *args, **kwargs):
        g = GeoIP()
        lat, lon = g.lat_lon(ip_address)
        user_location = super(StoryForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user_location.latitude = lat
        user_location.longitude = lon
        user_location.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: If you add in some debugging logging in the `save()` method, do you find that you get `lat` and `lon` as expected? What happens if you try IPs that resolve to a location and IPs that don't? Did the `user_location` object get created correctly?

Comment: StoryForm.save(...) is not returning anything(a.k.a None in python). Do `obj = user_location.save(*args, **kwargs)` and on a separate line below do `return obj`

Comment: I get the same error. Stumped. The GeoIP object is not called at all in the view. Could that be part of the problem?